# How do I disable the power grid in the Seoul Power Plant?

Tags: watch-dogs-2

I've been trying for roughly half an hour to get past the Seoul power plant in the Hack Teh World main mission. I've been toggling the systems but they light up then go back to blue.

How do I get the powergrid to overload? I got the dialog triggered but nothing happens.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your goal here is to turn all the sectors in the big monitoring screen *red*. You can't see this in nethack mode. Switch to regular mode, and toggle switches until you get the desired result. Its ridiculously simple, and just a matter of trial and error at this point, but it saves a *ton* of frustration